# Auto-generate Javadoc comments in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, automation

Is it possible to auto-generate Javadoc comments for each method in one class in Eclipse (Indigo)?

Comment: Select the methods in Outline and press Alt-Shift-J. You may need to edit the templates to get the exact comments you want.

Comment: This is `cmd+alt+J` on Mac

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There may be a better approach, but if you expand the class in Package Explorer, select the methods you would to document, then right-click and select "Source -> Generate Element Comment" that will add comments for all the selected methods.

Comment: thx for you answer!!! I just tried this approach and it only works for one method...(Source -> Generate Element Comment). Is this I problem only I have???

Comment: @maximus: Did you definitely *select* multiple methods to start with, e.g. by ctrl-click?

Comment: @maximus: You need to select the method in view Outline, if you select them in Editor the comment will apply only to first one if any.

Comment: This approach works best only for undocumented methods. For better coverage and accuracy, use JAutodoc eclipse plugin as suggested by Krzysztof Jabłoński: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12580831/904375

Comment: Go to **Window** > **Open in view** > **Outline** and then select as many as methods you want and then **Source** > **Generate Element Comment**

Comment: There is also `ALT + SHIFT + J` :)

Answer (score 26):

The other choice might be to double click on the name of the method, then ALT+Shift+J shortcut.

Comment: For MacOS, use CMD + Option + J

Answer (score 11):

There also exist external tools for javadoc generation, for example [JAutodoc eclipse plugin](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/). It is possible to customize it's templates to suit your expectation.

Comment: How to customize its template. 

I want tor remove those annoying // TODO: Auto-generated Javadoc

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse you have possiblity to create java doc template, and then just what need to do is type java-dock block `/**` above the element you want to document.

In case when the code is generate, the templates also generate the java-doc.

All this and even more you will be able to configure in Window -> Preferences, Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates -> Comments

Comment: thx! btw is there a way to create these type of command for all methods at once?

Comment: @maximus, The solution for that is Jon Skeet answer.